# WP, get custom post type edit-posts table to show up elsewhere

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

The scenario,

i have 2 custom post types,
"objects" and "settings" where settings must not be visible in menus.

Instead, Objects is a menu and underneath it is default sub pages:

```
Objects
    |-> All Objects
    |-> Add new
    |-> (Settings)
```

Now, i added a new sub page menu to Objects which will be Settings,
but these settings need to actually be Settings custom post type.
(Settings post type is needed to create multiple settings and to be able to choose between those in different Objects.)

Normally it would look like this:

```
Objects
    |-> All Objects
    |-> Add new

Settings
    |-> All Settings
    |-> Add new
```

So, how can i get custom posttype edit page to appear on a sub page ?

(I tried with jQuery load() but there will occour some JS collisions, so not the best solution.)

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Adminimize](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/adminimize/) plugin for hiding some entries in your menus.